# Set consisting of all unoriented cobordism classes of smooth closed $n$-manifolds can be made into additive group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, characteristic-classes, cobordism

How do I see that the set $\mathfrak{N}_n$ consisting of all unoriented cobordism classes of smooth closed $n$-manifolds can be made into an additive group?

Comment: Addition is disjoint union, inverse is the manifold itself.

Comment: Did this question suddenly pop into your mind? Were you doing your laundry and suddenly wondered that with no context at all surrounding it? There are groups of every cardinality, so trivially every set can be made into a group. Maybe the *context* surrounding your question helps in determining what the precise group law is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A natural operation is disjoint union. If $[M]$, $[N]$ are cobordism classes of $M, N$ respectively then define the sum to be $[M] + [N] = [M \sqcup N]$, the cobordism class of the disjoint union of the two.

This is clearly associative, commutative and has identity as the null manifold class $[\emptyset]$. $[M] + [M] = [M \sqcup M]$, and as $M \sqcup M$ bounds $M \times [0, 1]$ (in the unoriented category!), $2[M] = 0$, so a cobordism class is it's own inverse.

The resulting additive group is denoted as $\Omega_n^{un}$, called the $n$-th unoriented cobordism group of a point. A classic question in topology is to compute these groups. Some examples are $\Omega_0^{un} \cong \Bbb Z/2$, $\Omega_1^{un} \cong 0$, $\Omega_2^{un} \cong \Bbb Z/2$, $\Omega_3^{un} \cong 0$, $\Omega_4^{un} \cong \Bbb Z/2 \times \Bbb Z/2$ and $\Omega_5^{un} \cong \Bbb Z/2$.